# Unable to send POST data using fetch: React

Tags: javascript, php, cors, fetch

I'm trying to send POST data to the PHP script on a different `origin` using javascript [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in react. I've got a CORS policy error as can be seen below:

[image]

In order to solve the above problem, i added these two lines to my PHP script:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
```

But i'm still unable to get my problem solved. The POST data is not being sent.

**JS code:**

```
fetch('http://localhost/articles-mania/publish.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,  // JSON Object 
    headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      responseMsg: response.msg
    })
})
```

**PHP Script:**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');

$title = $_POST['article_title'];
echo json_encode(array('msg' => $title));
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can remove any mention of React in your question as it's front-end agnostic. This is a CORS issue

Comment: @Tholle, Done !

Comment: @MUHAMMADSiyab, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try allowing the `OPTIONS` method as that is used to perform the pre-flight request...

Change this:

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');`

To This:

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS');`

Comment: Your answer didn't help? any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I just came across a similar issue where it seemed like I had all my CORS settings properly in place. What worked for me was adding a JSON.stringify() to the object you're passing into the body parameter.

E.g.

```
fetch('http://localhost/articles-mania/publish.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),  // JSON Object 
    headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      responseMsg: response.msg
    })
})
```